# How to create waveform on a control when the window form is deactivated?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating live waveform on a control, such that as the waveform gets created it keeps shifting towards left. While the waveform is getting created, I bring a window, say skype window, in front of my control such that half of the waveform already created is behind that window. Now when the waveform is getting created while recording is on, the portion that is behind the skype window becomes white in a color that is of the background of control. And this white patch keeps shifting towards left.

When I minimize the skype window, the waveform is reinstated as earlier and it created as it should be.

How to redeem my waveform when the form on which the control is deactivated or minimized?